# Entity Framework: read only property vs parameter-less method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider following class

```
public class AccountGroup : Entity<int>
{
    public AccountGroup()
    {
        Accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
        Groups = new HashSet<AccountGroup>();
    }

    // option 1 - read only properties
    public bool IsRoot { get { return Parent == null; } }
    public bool IsLeaf { get { return !Groups.Any(); } }
    public Account MainAccount { get { return Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Type == AccountType.MainAccount); } }

    // option 2 - parameter-less methods
    //public bool IsRoot() { return Parent == null; }
    //public bool IsLeaf() { return !Groups.Any();  }
    //public Account GetMainAccount() { return Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == AccountType.MainAccount); }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<Account> Accounts { get; private set; }
    public virtual ISet<AccountGroup> Groups { get; private set; }
    public virtual AccountGroup Parent { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to "enrich" the class above, which option approach should I use.

### Option 1

Should I use read only parameters knowing that EF does not like them (trying to use IsRoot in Where clause throws ex, with `The specified type member 'IsRoot' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

### Option 2

Or should I go with parameter-less methods (not sure what would be disadvantages)

In general (not considering EF), which approach is preferred considering above when functionality is equivalent (i.e. I get the same functionality if I invoke `.IsRoot` or `.IsRoot()`)

Comment: why not get your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `: Entity<int>` that s not a good design. dont do that. doesnt feel right.

Comment: @DarthVader Entity is my own class (abstract) that I use as base class for all domain models which have a primary key. So my Entity<T> has a property T Id {get; set}...Why is that a bad design?

Comment: @HatSoft ...because I am not asking for code review? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsRoot` feels more like a property to me. It represents current state of the object, doesn't actually do anything when invoked other than report that state, and generally getters/setters in .NET are properties.

There are other things to consider, a JSON/XML serializer will not serialize `IsRoot()` but will for `IsRoot` as a property. Generally speaking a lot of things in .NET hinge off of properties, so often they are the better choice.

EF wouldn't like `IsRoot()` either, it just doesn't know how to translate IsRoot into SQL, whether it's a property or method.

Comment: "EF wouldn't like IsRoot() either...", I just ran into this :)...So from EF standpoint there is no advantage of using method and additionally I am using JSON so using property is advantage...Tnx

Comment: The work around is to call `AsEnumerable()`, at that point everything in your LINQ chain will get slurped up into memory and then you can invoke any method you want. The downside being you may pull more into memory than is ideal.

Comment: yep...In my repositories (data layer) I will have to use (t=>t.ParentId == null), elsewhere I can use IsRoot property. Perhaps redundant, but no other choice in order to have expressive API...

Answer (score 0):

In general (as you say, not taking limitations of EF into account), the approach for domain models in this particular context would probably be a read-only property.

Consider that the property is simply checking state, not modifying it in any way.  A read-only property conveys, outside of the object, that it's just returning a piece of information.  On the other hand, a method could be potentially destructive in that it might modify information.

This would be particularly true if the method returned `void` of course, which isn't the case here, so this could be considered a borderline issue (and not even a question in languages which don't have "properties" but just use accessor methods, which under the hood is what a "property" does).

My vote is for a property when checking state and a method when commanding the object to modify state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried decorating `IsRoot` with [[NotMapped]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  The NotMapped attribute should prevent Entity Framework from complaining about properties that it's unable to persist and allow you to express that as a property.

Comment: That is not an issue. I am using fluent style (Ignore(t=>t.IsRoot)) and that works, but if you try to use the property is statement that generates the query it will throw an exception (because there is no such column). To use the property you have to materialize the data and then you can use it...